# Relacionamento 0..1 na prática

Tags: sql, modelagem

Tendo as seguintes tabelas:

> - pedido
> - endereço
> - mesa

Os pedidos podem ser efetuados na pizzaria, ou seja, para uma mesa. Pode ser uma entrega(endereço) ou pode ser um pedido para viagem, onde ele não pertence a ninguém. No SQL da tabela pedido, no momento tenho o seguinte:

```
CREATE TABLE pedido  
(  
cod_ped INT NOT NULL,  
cod_mesa INT,  
cod_end INT,  
val_ped DECIMAL(18,2),  
tipo_ped CHAR(1) NOT NULL,   
data_ins DATETIME,  
CONSTRAINT pk_cod_ped  
PRIMARY KEY(cod_ped),  
CONSTRAINT fk_cod_mesa  
FOREIGN KEY (cod_mesa)   
REFERENCES mesa(cod_mesa),  
CONSTRAINT fk_cod_end  
FOREIGN KEY (cod_end)   
REFERENCES endereco(cod_end),     
);
```

Porém, como explicado, um mesmo pedido pode pertencer tanto a 1 mesa/endereço quanto a nenhum. Criando a chave estrangeira, estaria obrigando este pedido a ter um endereço e uma mesa. Como resolver este problema?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se um campo for chave estrangeira, e ao mesmo tempo puder receber um valor nulo, então ele não obrigado a ter valor. Porém, se tiver valor, tem que ser referente à tabela referenciada.

Então, do jeito vc que criou está certo. Basta mandar valor nulo nos campos `cod_mesa` e `cod_end` que será um pedido para viagem.